# I am working on my calculator and it can't do floats

Tags: python

```
e = 'p'
def sum(a, b):
    return (a + b)
def sub(a, b):
    return (a - b)
def mul(a, b):
    return (a * b)
def div(a, b):
    return (a / b)
while True:
    a = int(input('Enter 1st number: '))
    b = input('Enter operator:')
    c = int(input('Enter 2nd number: '))
    if b == '+':
        d = sum
        e = 'sum'
    if b == '-':
        d = sub
        e = 'difference'
    if b == '*':
        d = mul
        e = 'product'
    if b == '/':
        d = div
        e = 'quotient'
    print('the '  +e+ f' of {a} and {c} is {d(a, c)}')
    print('.        .')
```

it simply can't do floats
and I need it  to do floats because
I want it to do floats and integers

Comment: Instead of writing garbage text you could have written an actual specific question that you want to ask.

Comment: If you want it to do floats, why did you use `int()` and not `float()`?

Comment: @mkrieger1 why is he calling a function `sum` and shadowing the built in one? Why isn't he giving variables meaningful names instead of `b` , `c` and so on? What for is `e` initialized before while loop? So many questions so little answers XD I guess mostly, cause "why not"

Comment: @Gameplay - the `e` was probably initialized to make a linter be quiet about a NameError in the print command in the case where `b` is not a valid operator.  Of course, that print would still fail due to `d` not being initialized to a callable when it actually runs.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using int(), you can use float() which is compatible with both floats and integers.

```
a = float(input('Enter 1st number: '))
b = input('Enter operator:')
c = float(input('Enter 2nd number: '))
```